# Inserting column from sheet2 into sheet1 in Excel without zeroes on unavailable data?

Tags: excel, excel-2011

I am trying to get a column from one sheet and putting it in another. I am pulling the "names" column from this sheet: **this is sheet2**
[image: Sheet2]

and putting it into another sheet (sheet1) by using =sheet2!A3 and =sheet2!A4 and then dragging down to the bottom of the excel page to fill the formulas. The problem that I am having, is that for data that is not in sheet2 that it is still trying to get, I am getting zeroes like this, all the way to the bottom of the page: **This is sheet 1 after I pull the column from sheet2**
[image: What I am getting in Sheet1 when I pull the column from sheet2]

How do I prevent these zeroes from appearing? I would assume there is a way to "copy data in column until the bottom of the data". Basically, how do I make it so that as "sheet2" grows in size, "sheet1" will also, but without the zeroes?
(The cell format is in "general" if that helps, and I am using Excel 2011 for Mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1)=TRUE,"",A1)`

Formula is... if that if the cell is blank, show an empty cell instead of 0. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How would I add that to my other formula? I can only have on formula per cell, correct? @Michael Hwang

Comment: The list of names on sheet 1 already have the equation that gets them from sheet2

Comment: replace the formula in sheet1 with this one.

Comment: Then it would no longer be able to pull names from sheet, because the value of the cells in sheet1 are pulled from sheet2 with the `=sheet2!A3` formula.

Comment: is there a way to add your formula to the `=sheet2!A3` formula?